# Vue: pass data to dynamic component

Tags: dynamic, vue.js, components

According to official help (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html), I have done the following code for dynamic component.

It easy to pass props into function resolve().

But the question is, how to pass taskId before 'resolve' function - required VAR instead of fixed value '1341'?

Many thanks!

```
Vue.component('task-name', function(resolve, reject){
    
    // var instead '1341'?

    axios.post("http://my-cite.com/taskname", {taskId: '1341'}).then(function (response){
        
        resolve({
            
            props: ['taskId'],

            data: function(){
                return {
                    response: response
                }
            },
          
            template: '<div>I am async! And the response is: {{response}}</div>'           
        })
    })
```

})

Comment: Where is the value you want to pass to the component going to come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-bind`

```
<div is="task-name" v-bind="myProp"></div>
```

where `myProp` is `{taskId: '1341'}`

Comment: I think the problem is that he's returning a component from a Promise, and wants the prop to be input to the Promise, when there is no component to handle props yet. I think it needs a wrapper component to handle the prop.